# Efficiency of passing arrays to a function vs unpickling the array inside the function in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, performance

Sorry in advance, I know almost nothing about efficiency, so I might need a little extra help.

I have a function that calls another function and it passes in pretty big arrays. Due to limitations in memory, I've just been saving the arrays to pickle files and unpickling inside the second function. Just for context, I have 64 pickle files that is each 47 megabytes (3 gigs total). I'm calling this function upwards of 100,000 times. I'm assuming that unpickling is far less efficient than unpickling once and passing the arrays, but I was wondering on the order of how much time I'd be losing in   doing the way I'm doing it now and whether there are more efficient ways of doing this

Comment: Have a look at `numpy.memmap` (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html).  Memmapping is in general keeping data on disk but accessing it as if it were loaded in memory.  `numpy.memmap` is a subclass of `numpy.ndarray` that is backed by a memmapped file.  The OS will do a good job of caching the data in RAM if it has free RAM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your requirement. If you pass an `array` to the function, python passes the `reference` of that array. Whereas if you pass the array in the form of unpacked arguments, objects comprising the array is passed.

Within the function if the order of your original array is not getting modified, it is better to pass it as reference i.e as a argument.

Answer (score 0):

If you memory limitations doesn't allow to keep all files in memory, you will read the file each time and pass `list` to another function (it will be passed by reference).